# Newbie DM: How do I keep all the game's information in my head?

Tags: dnd-5e, new-gm

Almost every year I have some kind of fever about D&D. I want to start DM'ing this thing. Then I realize how hard it is and give up again. So it's started again...
I do have friends that want's to be a part of it but they are too lazy to read the PHB.

I'm going to create my own scenario. I'm pretty good with improvisation and storytelling. So I think it's easier to come up with any kind of wild events on a road then to follow someone's guideline.

The problem is that it seems like the basic mechanics of the game is very difficult. I need to memorize all spells, skills, racial and class features, bonus abilities and also need to explain it to players. It feels like it's so hard for me only because of lack of practice. I don't want to stop the game and say "Hold on, let me check what this spell do!"

My main question is **how do I keep all that information in my head?**

It feels like I know all that small things like "how does this work" "when should I do this" but it's just too much for me to memorize. I'll definitely miss some core mechanics when I'll do my first game.

Comment: It looks like your question was marked as duplicate. If you feel the "original" does not answer your question, feel free to edit your question to indicate in which ways the "original" is not satisfactory